# WAS 8.5 Unable to find primary pool manager during failover processing for a resource with a JNDI name XXX

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, websphere, datasource

I am using WAS8.5 with JDBC. At some point of time I am getting the below exception while retrieving connection from the data source.

**Exception :**

> Unable to find primary pool manager during failover processing for a resource with a JNDI name of XXX

**Additional Info:**

```
 - Data Base                  : Ms-SQL 2008 with sqljdbc-2005.jar
 - Connection timeout         : 300 seconds
 - Maximum connections        : 30  connections
 - Minimum connections        : 1 connections
 - Reap time                  : 180 seconds
 - Unused timeout             : 1800 seconds
 - Aged timeout               : 0 seconds
 - Purge policy               : EntirePool
 - Implementation Class Name  :
   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource
```

Any suggestion/solutions for the above issue will be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Typical, this exception[1] is thrown when the application is trying to get a connection after the shutdown request. Since the connection pool is unavailable after the shut down request, the errors are thrown.

Is this exception thrown during normal processing or during JVM shutdown? Can you attach or provide more messages from the SystemOut.log?

[1]
J2CA0020E: The
Connection Pool Manager could not allocate a Managed Connection:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: J2CA0695E: Unable to find primary pool
manager during failover processing for a resource with a JNDI name of XXX

Comment: In case it is after a shutdown request, how do we manage that? It is weird that some threads are still executing while the connection pool is already unavailable.